# Multiple React apps on express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a server on express.js and there is a static folder in its root directory, it contains several react apps, something like this:

```
app:
    static:
           react1
           react2
```

I am trying to make sure that when accessing the **/react1** and **/react2** addresses, the express will display the required application.

**app.js:**

```
app.use (express.static(path.join(__ dirname, "static")));
app.use ("/", indexRouter);
```

**index.router:**

```
router.get('/react1', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join (__dirname, '..', 'static', 'react1', 'index.html'))
});

router.get('/react2', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join (__dirname, '..', 'static', 'react2', 'index.html'))
});
```

When I try to navigate through these handles, I get a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js & index.router looks fine.
You might wanna add `*` to the router. 
For instance 
`router.get('/react1/*', (req, res) => {`

I think the issue is in how the static content is built.

Make sure to add `PUBLIC_URL` to build script in `package.json`. 
For instance: `"build": "PUBLIC_URL=/admin react-scripts build",`

You can refer this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Utq4cTuyshw) for a detailed explanation.